# Halcon - What is the fastest blur filter available

Tags: filter, blur, halcon

What is the fastets blur filter in Halcon?
I dont need a specific type of blur, I just need it to be blurred as fast as possible.. About 3/4 px in size.

Currently I am using the binomial_filter as it seems to be faster than the gaussian, but still slow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a faster filter.
You can see the demo compare_gauss_filters.hdev inside Halcon.
You can reduce the execution time only reducing the filter size.

Comment: Grazie! :) will have a look at that example

Answer (score 1):

The command for the mean filter is mean_image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find polynomial_filter in Halcon.
Nevertheless, you can try **mean_image**

Comment: Sorry, its binomial_filter.. not Polynomial.. I am updating the post. Anyway, binomial_filter on my pc takes 5.3ms and mean_image takes 6.9ms (average)

Answer (score 0):

A mean filter should be faster because it needs much fewer multiplications.